# Python script to transpose on basis of certain criteria

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a file containing data in following format:

abc 123 456
cde 45 32
efg 322 654
abc 445 856
cde 65 21
efg 147 384
abc 815 078
efg 843 286
and so on. How can transpose it into following format using Python:

abc 123 456 cde 45 32 efg 322 654
abc 445 856 cde 65 21 efg 147 348
abc 815 078           efg 843 286
Also, in case cde is missing after abc, it should insert blank spaces instead, since it is a fixed width file.
    With open ('abc. txt') as file:
            for lines in file.readlines()
                while lines[:3] =='abc'
                lines.replace('\n','')

I am new to python , would appreciate help on this!!

Comment: You should, please, show us the code you have written to solve this problem, and ask specific questions about any issues that arise.

Answer (score 0):

@Ritesh1111, Even You are new, you should start trying something.
Try with below code with few assumptions, It might not be 100% accurate, but you can start from here:

```
with open('abc.txt') as rd:
    data = rd.readlines()

full_detail={}
seq=['abc', 'cde', 'efg']  # Assuming the order of the sequences, also 1st must be present.   
for row in seq:
    full_detail[row] = []
last_processed = None

def get_next_seq_pos(last_seq_postition, seq):
    return last_seq_postition+1 if last_seq_postition < len(seq) - 1 else 0

for line in data:
    cline = line.strip().split(" ")
    if last_processed is None:
        data_seq_postition = seq.index(cline[0].strip())
        temp_data = " ".join([str(i) for i in cline[1:]])
        full_detail[seq[data_seq_postition]].append(temp_data)
        last_processed = seq[data_seq_postition]
    else:
        last_seq_postition = seq.index(last_processed)
        data_seq_postition = seq.index(cline[0].strip())
        next_seq_postition = get_next_seq_pos(last_seq_postition, seq)
        while(next_seq_postition != data_seq_postition):
            full_detail[seq[next_seq_postition]].append("   ")
            last_processed = seq[next_seq_postition]
            last_seq_postition = seq.index(last_processed)
            next_seq_postition = get_next_seq_pos(last_seq_postition, seq)
        full_detail[seq[data_seq_postition]].append(" ".join([str(i) for i in cline[1:]]))
        last_processed = seq[data_seq_postition]

data_length = len(full_detail[seq[0]])
for i in range(0,data_length):
    for row in seq:
        print row, full_detail[row][i],
    print
```

> #### Output

abc 123 456 cde 45 32 efg 322 654

abc 445 856 cde 65 21 efg 147 384

abc 815 078 cde  . .  efg 843 286